# Boundary point & critical point of a function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is it a must that all critical points are interior point for a function ?

My question is can a boundary point be critical point of a function??

Comment: Endpoints are not generally considered to be differentiable (because no two sided limits).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a great question that a student of mine once raised, and I realized that I had never seen any calculus book, or even analysis book, that addressed the question. On the one hand, if your function is defined on a closed interval, the two-sided derivative doesn't technically exist at the boundary points. On the other hand, it doesn't seem quite right to say that the function $f(x)=x^2$ isn't differentiable on the interval $[0,1]$, since the function obviously extends to any interval we want. What's the way out? As I understand it, boundary points are never critical points, *and that is by definition*. When you're doing the optimization strategy of finding all the critical points, you just always check the boundary points as an additional matter of course.

Comment: By the way thanks for the same

Comment: No problem! I think most calculus books aren't expecting their students to think this deeply about the matter.